# change file permmissons after copy them failed

Tags: php

I tried to to the following:

Copy files and folder from folder `.../myfolder/subfolder etc.`
to folder `.../anotherfolder/subfolder etc.`

Copy this works fine.

The Folder has permissions 0755 and, if I copy that, the new folder has the same permissions.

So I want to change the permission to 0644, I tried to do that with

```
if(!chmod($path, 0644)){ die("Error"); }
```

it failed with the message

> chmod(): Permission denied

my path is relative, the same as I used to copy.

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Thank for helping and explain

Comment: what are the file ownerships? Does PHP USER === owner of files?

Comment: You want to remove the x bit from the folder permissions? You are aware that you cannot access the folder content any longer then?

Comment: which web server do you use, apache for example ?

Comment: i use apache,nginx, so i think the owner must the same, cause i copy the files one step before, as i trie to change the permissions!?

Comment: `i use apache,nginx` - wha? you can't use both for one server (that I'm aware of)

Comment: I suppose you _could_ use nginx to forward to apache running PHP... but that seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @RainerS yes as you mention the script is executed by your webserver for example apache, then the user apache must be the owner of your directory. Maybe verify it is the case